# Why use a ThreadStaticAttribute field instead of a local Variable in the invoked Method?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was wondering why use a `ThreadStaticAttributed` field over a local variable. I don't see any difference between a local variable and a ThreadStaticField. Here is some code to furthermore underline my point:

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(doSomething);
    t1.Start();
}

[ThreadStaticAttribute]
static int secondNumber;

static void doSomething()
{
    int number = 3; 
    secondNumber = 7;
    Console.WriteLine(number);  //Compiles to 3
    Console.WriteLine(secondNumber);  //Compiles to 7
}
```

Now the following code will have the same result as the above:

```
static void Main()
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(doSomething);
    t1.Start();
}

static void doSomething()
{
    int number = 3; 
    int secondNumber = 7;
    Console.WriteLine(number);  //Compiles to 3
    Console.WriteLine(secondNumber);  //Compiles to 7
}
```

So what is the use of a `[ThreadStaticAttribute]` Field, if I can just as good use a local Variable in the Method?

Comment: And what happens when `doSomething` calls `doSomethingElse` and `doSomethingElse` calls `doSomethingThirdly` and `doSomethingThirdly` *also* uses `secondNumber`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever one could say `secondNumber` is unique to each and evry Thread. Meaning each Thread has a diffrent value for `secondNumber` and needs to instantiate it itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why use a ThreadStaticAttribute field over a local Variable in the invoked 
>   Method?

Because a local variable is not accessible outside of the method.

A lot of variables you access are thread static if you do web development. HttpContext.CURRENT - is different for every thread, for example.

And that is exactly the use case - sometimes you need to make some data available to third parties, but this - particularly in a server environment - often happens on a per thread scenario. You COULD put it in as parameter into a method call, but this would require a lot of parameters passed possibly through a lot of methods, so for certain things a ThreadStatic variable is better.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!
It gave me the Idea, how a `ThreadStatic` field might be used in the "real world".

Answer (score 4):

Scope and lifetime.

Scope: `public` thread-static fields are accessible from anywhere (other methods, other classes). Locals are only accessible in their immediate scope (this means a function cannot allocate-and-return data on the stack).

Lifetime: Locals only last as long as their stackframe lives. Thread-static values can last for as long as the life of the process.

There is a workaround: if you need thread-local storage shared by different methods in a long call-chain you can use an object (containing many properties) passed by-ref into the different methods - though you'll run into safety problems if you spawn new threads accessing the same object), e.g.:

```
class ThreadLocalValues {
    public Int32 SomeValue1;
    public String SomeValue2;
}

void Foo(ThreadLocalValues context) {
    context.SomeValue1 = 1;
    SomeOtherMethod( context, otherStuff, goesHere );
}
```

Instead of:

```
[ThreadStatic]
public static Int32 SomeValue1
[ThreadStatic]
public static String SomeValue2
```

Comment: How can i access the `secondNumber` from lets say the MainThread? i mean the MainThread has a diffrent value for `secondNumber` then the t1 thread.

Comment: @MilesA. if `secondNumber` is declared `ThreadStatic` then what you're describing is by-design. If you want to pass values to a child thread then you need to provide them as a parameter to the thread's start method or use a thread-synchronization system. Never use static variables for this.

Answer (score 0):

The first example shows a variable, which is a single instance static to all threads. Other threads can access the variable's value.

The second example gives each thread its own local variable. Other threads wouldn't be able to see the local variable.